# SwiftUI: Pause and Resume animation

Tags: swiftui

The idea is this: an object has a start position (A) and an end position (B). When the start button is pressed, the object moves from Ax, Ay to Bx, By. At an arbitrary point in time, you can stop its movement and continue.

I tried to implement this with a timer that moves the object every n time periods. It works, but the problem is that the timer eats up a lot of memory and when ten objects are created, the application freezes.

I do not ask you to do the task for me, but I will be very grateful if you tell me where to dig

Code currently in use

```
typealias RemainingDurationProvider<Value: VectorArithmetic> = (Value) -> TimeInterval
typealias AnimationWithDurationProvider = (TimeInterval) -> Animation
extension Animation {
  static let instant = Animation.linear(duration: 0.0001)
}
struct PausableAnimationModifier<Value: VectorArithmetic>: AnimatableModifier {
  @Binding var binding: Value
  @Binding var paused: Bool
  private let targetValue: Value
  private let remainingDuration: RemainingDurationProvider<Value>
  private let animation: AnimationWithDurationProvider
  var animatableData: Value
  init(binding: Binding<Value>, targetValue: Value, remainingDuration: @escaping RemainingDurationProvider<Value>, animation: @escaping AnimationWithDurationProvider, paused: Binding<Bool>) {
    _binding = binding
    self.targetValue = targetValue
    self.remainingDuration = remainingDuration
    self.animation = animation
    _paused = paused
    animatableData = binding.wrappedValue
  }
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .onChange(of: paused) { isPaused in
        if isPaused {
          withAnimation(.instant) {
            binding = animatableData
          }
        } else {
          withAnimation(animation(remainingDuration(animatableData))) {
            binding = targetValue
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
extension View {
  func pausableAnimation<Value: VectorArithmetic>(binding: Binding<Value>, targetValue: Value, remainingDuration: @escaping RemainingDurationProvider<Value>, animation: @escaping AnimationWithDurationProvider, paused: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
    self.modifier(PausableAnimationModifier(binding: binding, targetValue: targetValue, remainingDuration: remainingDuration, animation: animation, paused: paused))
  }
}
struct TestView: View {
  @State private var isPaused = false
  @State private var offsetX: Double = .zero
  @State private var startOffsetX: Double = .zero
  @State private var endOffsetX: Double = 200.0
  @State private var offsetY: Double = .zero
  @State private var startPositionY: Double = .zero
  @State private var endPositionY: Double = 500.0
  private let duration: TimeInterval = 6
  private var remainingDurationForX: RemainingDurationProvider<Double> {
    { currentAngle in duration * (1 - (currentAngle - startOffsetX) / (endOffsetX - startOffsetX)) }
  }
  private var remainingDurationForY: RemainingDurationProvider<Double> {
    { currentAngle in duration * (1 - (currentAngle - startPositionY) / (endPositionY - startPositionY)) }
  }
  private let animation: AnimationWithDurationProvider = { duration in
      .linear(duration: duration)
  }
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ZStack {
        VStack {
          HStack {
            Rectangle()
              .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
              .offset(x: offsetX, y: offsetY)
              .pausableAnimation(binding: $offsetX,
                        targetValue: endOffsetX,
                        remainingDuration: remainingDurationForX,
                        animation: animation,
                        paused: $isPaused)
              .pausableAnimation(binding: $offsetY,
                        targetValue: endPositionY,
                        remainingDuration: remainingDurationForY,
                        animation: animation,
                        paused: $isPaused)
            Spacer()
          }
          Spacer()
        }
      }
      HStack {
        ControllButton(text: “Start”, action: {
          offsetX = startOffsetX
          offsetY = startPositionY
          withAnimation(animation(duration)) {
            offsetX = endOffsetX
            offsetY = endPositionY
          }
        })
        ControllButton(text: “NewPosition”, action: {
          startOffsetX = endOffsetX
          startPositionY = endPositionY
          endOffsetX = 300
          endPositionY = 30
        })
        ControllButton(text: isPaused ? “Resume” : “Pause”, action: {
          isPaused = !isPaused
        })
        ControllButton(text: “Stop”, action: {
          offsetX = .zero
          offsetY = .zero
        })
      }
      .padding(.bottom)
    }
  }
}
struct ControllButton: View {
  var text: String
  var action: () -> ()
  var body: some View {
    Button(text) {
      action()
    }
    .padding()
    .background(Color.yellow)
    .frame(height: 35)
    .cornerRadius(10)
  }
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you doing it right now?

Comment: I have now refactored the code from this example: https://github.com/globulus/swiftui-pausable-animation. Maybe I do not have enough knowledge, but to get the result I need, I call the modifier twice (for X and for Y separately).

Comment: Would need to see your actual code to give a better insight, but my first guess is try to combine the two modifier into one. Also note simulator tend to slow down quite a lot when doing complex animations, try run it on a physical device if you can.

Comment: I tested the timer options on a physical device. I have edited the question and added the code. This option, even if you create an array of 100 objects, works without freezes. But I don't like the way it looks. All attempts to make this modifier fit for two axes immediately failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure the exact intent of your code, but here's something you could try:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var recs: [(AnyView, UUID)] = []
    @State var isPaused: Bool = true
    @State var shouldUpdate: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                ForEach(recs, id: \.1) { $0.0 }
            }
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Button(isPaused ? "Start" : "Pause") {
                    isPaused.toggle()
                }
                Button("Add") {
                    recs.append(
                        (AnyView(
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                .pausableAnimation(
                                    startingPosition: .init(x: .random(in: 0..<300), y: 0),
                                    endingPosition: .init(x: .random(in: 0..<300), y: .random(in: 300..<700)),
                                    isPaused: $isPaused,
                                    shoudUpdate: $shouldUpdate
                                )
                        ), UUID())
                    )
                }
                Button("Update") {
                    shouldUpdate = true
                }
                Button("Reset") {
                    isPaused = true
                    recs.removeAll()
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            .tint(.orange)
        }
    }
}

extension CGPoint {
    func isCloseTo(_ other: CGPoint) -> Bool {
        (self.x - other.x) * (self.x - other.x) + (self.y - other.y) * (self.y - other.y) < 10
    }
}

struct PausableAnimation: ViewModifier {
    @State var startingPosition: CGPoint
    @State var endingPosition: CGPoint
    @Binding var isPaused: Bool
    @Binding var shouldUpdate: Bool
    private let publisher = Timer.TimerPublisher(interval: 0.1, runLoop: .main, mode: .default).autoconnect()
    @State private var fired = 0
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .position(startingPosition)
            .animation(.linear, value: startingPosition)
            .onReceive(publisher) { _ in
                if !isPaused && !startingPosition.isCloseTo(endingPosition){
                    startingPosition.x += (endingPosition.x - startingPosition.x) / CGFloat(20 - fired)
                    startingPosition.y += (endingPosition.y - startingPosition.y) / CGFloat(20 - fired)
                    fired += 1
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: shouldUpdate) { newValue in
                if newValue == true {
                    updatePosition()
                    shouldUpdate = false
                }
            }
    }
    
    func updatePosition() {
        endingPosition = .init(x: .random(in: 0..<300), y: .random(in: 0..<700))
        fired = 0
    }
}

extension View {
    func pausableAnimation(startingPosition: CGPoint, endingPosition: CGPoint, isPaused: Binding<Bool>, shoudUpdate: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        modifier(
            PausableAnimation(
                startingPosition: startingPosition,
                endingPosition: endingPosition,
                isPaused: isPaused,
                shouldUpdate: shoudUpdate
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Basically the idea here is in each `PausableAnimation`, a `TimerPublisher` is created to fire every 0.1 second. Anytime the publisher fires, it will move from `startingPosition` and `endingPosition` by 1/20 of the distance between them.

I used a `CGPoint` to keep both x and y information in a single variable. However, using two separate variables shouldn't change much of the code beside needing to pass in more data in the initializer.

I wrapped the modified view in a `(AnyView, UUID)`, so I can add more of them into an array and display them through `ForEach`, dynamically.

Feel free to play around, I hope the idea is clear.

Comment: Yes, this is an elegant solution to my question. Thank you very much. Very clearly written. I've been trying to solve this problem for two days now. Thanks again!

Comment: Causes a little complexity two points: the animation doesn't match the native one and there is no control over the duration time

Comment: @RatitMatarit I didn't expose a way to change duration directly, but in the `.onReceive` modifier, there's `CGFloat(20 - fired)`, that basically controls how many times it will listen to the publisher. At the moment it will listen for 20 times, and the timer interval 0.1 second * 20, the duration of the animation is 2 second. Changing the 20 will effectively change how long the animation will run. You can definitely make it a view variable if you want.

Comment: @RatitMatarit About *'the animation doesn't match the native one'*, can you be more specific about it?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to change `CGFloat (20 - fired)`, but if you leave one object and create the same one next to it, just animate it with normal animation, you can see how much the speed differs

Comment: @RatitMatarit They have different speed because at the moment, they are starting and ending at random locations, which means despite they all travel for 2 second, they travel for different distance, thus the different speed. To ensure they have the same speed, you should change the `startingPosition` and `endingPosition`, to make sure they all travel for the same distance.

Comment: @RatitMatarit Also, at the moment, the movement won't perfectly sync because they all uses different timer, which might have up to 0.1 second difference between when they would actually start moving. To force them syncing, you should create a timer from the parent view, and pass the timer to the modifier.